# Solving an ODE that resulted from method of characteristics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to follow a development in which an ODE is solved.  The equation arises from using the method of characteristics to solve a PDE. We have $\dot{x}=v$. The ODE is
$$
m(x) v \frac{dv}{dx} = F(x) - v^{2} \frac{d}{dx}(m(x))
$$
with the substitution $\xi = v^{2}$ we have the following expression
$$
m(x) \frac{d \xi}{d x} + 2 \xi \frac{d}{dx}(m(x)) = 2 F(x)
$$
The solution should be

$$
C = \frac{m^{2}(x)}{2} v^{2} - \int m(x) F(x) dx
$$
But I cannot get to that solution. My first problem arises by not being able to identify what kind of ODE this is.
I hope you can help me get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$m(x) \frac{d \xi}{d x} + 2 \xi \frac{d}{dx}(m(x)) = 2 F(x)$$
$$m(x) d \xi + 2 \xi d(m(x)) = 2 F(x)dx$$
Multiply by $m(x)$:
$$m^2(x) {d \xi} + 2m(x) \xi d(m(x)) = 2m(x) F(x)dx$$
$$m^2(x) {d \xi} +  \xi d(m^2(x)) = 2m(x) F(x)dx$$
$$d \xi m^2(x) = 2m(x)  F(x)dx$$
Integrate.
$$ \xi m^2(x) =C+ 2\int m(x)  F(x)dx$$
$$ C= (vm(x))^2 -2\int m(x)  F(x)dx$$

Comment: Wow, yes. Now I see it. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome @ErickSolis